# PPTP-Connection not possible because required service can't start

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, pptp

I'm in China and trying to use expressvpn. openvpn doesn't work properly in the wifi, so the people from expressvpn told me to use a pptp-connection instead. I've set that up but I can't connect. When I click on connect I get the following message

> Starting the service, that provides the VPN-connection, failed

Any ideas what I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPtP creates a GRE tunnel after the authentication. GRE is a Point to Point (PtP) protocol.
If you have a private IP and the router is doing NAT (most probably the case), in order to establish the connection your router should support GRE (TCP Proto 47) passthrough.

If that is not enabled, you won't be able to connect to PPtP VPN.